# Find a string in a MySQL field with concurrences

Tags: mysql, string, find

Is there any function in MySQL where I especifies the concurrences numbers for the search?

Example:

```
lcString = "My name-is-Harry-Potter"
```

In Visual FoxPro you can use this:

```
?AT('a',lcString,1) && where 1 means "get me the first concurrence"

OutPut = 5
```

Or

```
?AT('-',lcString,3) && where 3 means "get me the third concurrence"

OutPut = 17
```

I was looking for a similar function in mysql but I can't find it.

Thank you all...!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `SUBSTRING_INDEX` and `LENGTH` MySQL functions to achieve that. This is what MySQL's [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index) says about `SUBSTRING_INDEX`:

> Returns the substring from string str before count occurrences of the
>   delimiter

So, you can wrap that inside `LENGTH` to get the occurrence, e.g.:

```
SELECT LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX('My name-is-Harry-Potter', 'a', 1)) + 1

SELECT LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX('My name-is-Harry-Potter', '-', 3)) + 1
```